# Unit Converter using Javascript arrays (or objects)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm building a unit converter on Javascript. What I want to do is store or pre-define all the unit values in an array like this:

```
var converter_table = {
    'mass' : {
        'kilogram' : 1000,
        'gram' : 1,
        'ounce' : .035274,
        'pound' : .00220462
    },

    'length' : {
        'kilometer' : 1000,
        'meter' : 1
    }
};
```

And then be able to pull out the values and make calculations based on user input.  For instance:

```
var quantity = 25, 
    category = 'mass',
    from_unit = 'kilogram',
    to_unit = 'pound';


var result = quantity * converter_table.category.from_unit * converter_table.category.to_unit;

alert(result);
```

Except, of course, converter_table.category.from_unit is undefined.  Is there a way to pull this off?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic object property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamic-object-property-name)

Comment: Note the correct spelling of the base [SI unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units#Units_and_prefixes) for distance is metre, a "meter" is a device for measuring things (like a water meter). You may need a thesaurus to convert one to the other to allow for user variances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array notation:

```
var result = quantity * converter_table[category][from_unit] * converter_table[category][to_unit];
```

Comment: It's not that simple. Usually a common (intermediate) unit is required so when converting from say miles per hour to knots, the conversion goes m/h -> km/h -> knots. Otherwise you need to store a conversion factor for every combination of conversions.

Comment: @RobG All the unit values are converted to their equivalent to a common unit.  For instance, the common unit for length is meter. So the kilometer value is 1000, the centimeter value would be .01. If you want to convert, 2 km to cm, it's as simple as multiplying the 2 x 1000 x .01.

Comment: The question wasn't about the algorithm, just how to access his object with variable names. In any case, looks like he pre-selected the common conversion factor that he cares about.

Comment: @Kama—using a common base you still need to work out whether to use the product or its inverse: kg to lb `1000*0.00220462 = 2.2lb`, lb to kg `1/(0.00220462*1000) = 0.45kg`. Try lb to oz: `0.00220462*0.035274 = 0.00007775` when you want `0.035274/0.00220462 = 16oz`.

Comment: oooh! you're right! So...how do we determine which equation to use given a particular user selection?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a list/dictionary of functions instead of numbers. Some units like °F and °C require multiplying and adding a number.

An example of this in use:
https://github.com/wk1093/unit-conv/blob/master/unitlist.js

Basic Example:

```js
class Unit {
    constructor(to, from) {
        this.to = to;
        this.from = from;
    }
}

unitlist = {
    'length': {
        'nm': new Unit(function(a) { return a * 1e-9; }, function(a) { return a / 1e-9; }),
        'um': new Unit(function(a) { return a * 1e-6; }, function(a) { return a / 1e-6; }),
        'mm': new Unit(function(a) { return a * 1e-3; }, function(a) { return a / 1e-3; }),
        'cm': new Unit(function(a) { return a * 1e-2; }, function(a) { return a / 1e-2; }),
        'dm': new Unit(function(a) { return a * 1e-1; }, function(a) { return a / 1e-1; }),
        'm': new Unit(function(a) { return a; }, function(a) { return a; }),
        'dam': new Unit(function(a) { return a * 1e1; }, function(a) { return a / 1e1; }),
        'hm': new Unit(function(a) { return a * 1e2; }, function(a) { return a / 1e2; }),
        'km': new Unit(function(a) { return a * 1e3; }, function(a) { return a / 1e3; }),
        'in': new Unit(function(a) { return a * 0.0254; }, function(a) { return a / 0.0254; }),
        'ft': new Unit(function(a) { return a * 0.3048; }, function(a) { return a / 0.3048; }),
        'yd': new Unit(function(a) { return a * 0.9144; }, function(a) { return a / 0.9144; }),
        'mi': new Unit(function(a) { return a * 1609.344; }, function(a) { return a / 1609.344; }),
        'nmi': new Unit(function(a) { return a * 1852; }, function(a) { return a / 1852; }),
    },
    'mass': {
       ...
    }
}
```

Then to use it:

```js
if (getTypeOfUnit(TO) == getTypeOfUnit(FROM)) {
  var units = unitlist[getTypeOfUnit(TO)];

  // Convert input unit to base unit
  var baseval = units[FROM].to(NUMBER);

  // Convert base unit to output unit
  var result = units[TO].from(baseval);
  console.log(result);
  }
}
```

This is my first answer on StackOverflow, so if I got anything wrong please let me know.